# Create lambda using aws cdk with 2 different language in one project

Tags: aws-cdk

I need to create lambda using 2 different language in one project cdk.

1. Typescript (for general purpose)
2. Python (for data engineering that use python library like panda, numpy, etc)
   I expect if I do something like cdk deploy.. all of my lambda will be deployed using it's environment
   Is it possible?

Any answer will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little vague so I'm not sure exactly what you are going for, but if you are just wanting to create two lambda functions where one is written in `Typescript` and the other is written in `Python`, then that is fairly straightforward. You just need to specify the runtime.

Here is some basic boilerplate for `Python` flavored `CDK` which deploys two different lambda functions.

```py
from aws_cdk import aws_lambda as _lambda

my_typescript_lambda = _lambda.Function(
    scope=self,
    id="typescript_lambda",
    runtime=_lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_14_X,
    # Path is relative to where you execute cdk
    code=_lambda.Code.from_asset(
        "lambda_funcs/typescript_lambda"
    ),
    handler="typescript_lambda.handler",
    description="A lambda function written in Typescript",
)

my_python_lambda = _lambda.Function(
    scope=self,
    id="python_lambda",
    runtime=_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_9,
    code=_lambda.Code.from_asset(
        path="lambda_funcs/python_lambda"
    ),
    handler="python_lambda.lambda_handler",
    description="A lambda function written in python",
)
```